# Divide N elements in 3 sets

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

Given N elements in an array where ith element has A[i] value.Now we need to divide these N elements in 3 sets in such a way that difference between sum of all elements in set1 and set3 is minimised.

That is :

```
Sum of set3 - Sum of set 1 is minimum
```

Main point to note is that

```
Sum of SET1 elements <= Sum of SET2 elements <= Sum of SET3 elements
```

Sets should satisfy this condition.

So we need to find sum of elements in Set1,Set2 and Set3 respectively.

Let if N =3 and array be [2,3,1] then answer would have been

```
Set1: 1 
Set2: 2
Set3: 3
```

As this is best case possible.

Now how to solve this for given N and array.

Comment: That sounds NP-hard. It looks like it would be easy to adapt a polynomial-time solver for this problem to solve ordinary knapsack problems.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yeah I know.Any brute solution that can be done if N is at max 20.?